# How to show date without time in RSS feed pubDate field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

I have created an rss version 2 page(rssfeed.aspx) in C#.Below is the code that i have tried

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="RSSFeed.aspx.cs" Inherits="RSSFeed" ContentType="text/xml" %>
<asp:repeater id="rptrRSSFeed" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <rss version="2.0">
                        <channel>
                        <title>PA Office of Attorney General Press RSS Feed</title>
                        <description>The latest press releases from the PA Office of Attorney General.</description>
                        <copyright>(c) 2007, PA Office of Attorney General</copyright>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <item>
                        <title><%#RemoveIllegalCharacters(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title")) %></title>
                        <link><%# Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/"+"Media_and_Resources/Press_Releases/Press_Release/?pid="+ DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%></link>
                        <pubDate><%#String.Format("{0:ddd, d MMM yyyy}",DateTime.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReleaseDate").ToString())) %></pubDate>
                        <description><%#RemoveIllegalCharacters(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Description"))%></description>
                    </item>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </channel>
            </rss>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:repeater>
```

But the pubdate shows in datetime format. I want only the date part there.How can i achieve that in RSS?

Below is the image that got on browsing this page in IE

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "shows" in datetime format? What are you using to view it? It sounds like this is more likely to be due to whatever's displaying the data than the RSS you're creating.

Comment: While browsing that page in browsers like IE, FF,chrome etc

Comment: Have you tried using "view source" to check what you're actually generating?

Comment: Hi @Jon Skeet ,in view sourse of iE and FF it shows as Thu, 18 Sep 2014, but after rendering it shows the time also,any idea?

Comment: Right. So this isn't about how you generate the RSS at all - it's just about how browsers choose to display it. That's nothing to do with C# or ASP.NET, and I suggest you experiment with a hard-coded RSS file. It's entirely possible that there's no way of telling browsers to only display a date...